# Calculating a Frechet derivative of a function of functions

Tags: analysis, frechet-derivative

I have been attempting this problem for quite a while. The problem is to show that the following function $$F((f))(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f^2(t)\cos(t)dt$$ is differentiable on the normed vector space $C[0,1]$ equipped with the norm $||f||=\underset{x\in[0,1]}\max|f(x)|$, and to then compute its derivative.

I don't really know where to go from here. I know that the frechet derivative is defined as a linear operator $T:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ that satisfies

$$\underset{h\rightarrow0}\lim \frac{||F(f+h)-F(f)-T(h)||}{||h||}=0$$

I though that things would become clear after writing everything out, but I'm stuck right around here:
$$\frac{\underset{x\in[0,1]}\max |\int_{0}^{x}[f^2(t)+2f(t)h(t)+h^2(t)]\cos(t)-f^2(t)\cos(t)dt-T(h)|}{\underset{x\in[0,1]}\max |h(t)|}$$

Do I show that this goes to zero in the limit as $h$ approaches the constant zero function? Apart from the obvious cancellation of the $f^2(t)\cos(t)$ term I don't know how to proceed. I would greatly appreciate some help here. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need to find a candidate for $T$. Using Gateaux variation, we see that
\begin{align}
T(f)g=&\ \frac{d}{dt}F(f+tg)\Big|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}\int^x_0(f(s)+tg(s))^2\cos(s)\ ds\Big|_{t=0}\\
=&\ 2 \int^x_0 f(s)\cos(s) g(s)\ ds.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\|F(f+g)-F(f)-T(f)g\|_\infty=&\ \Big\|\int^x_0 [(f(s)+g(s))^2-f^2(s)-2f(s)g(s)]\cos(s)\ ds \Big\|_\infty\\
=&\ \Big\|\int^x_0 g^2(s)\cos(s)\ ds \Big\|_\infty \leq \| g\|_\infty^2 \Big\|\int^x_0\cos(s)\ ds \Big\|_\infty\\
\leq&\ \|g\|_\infty^2
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{\|F(f+g)-F(f)-T(f)g\|_\infty}{\|g\|_\infty} \leq \|g\|_\infty \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $\|g\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$. Thus, we see that the Frechet derivative of $F(f)$ is 
\begin{align}
(T(f)g )(x) = 2\int^x_0 f(s)g(s)\cos(s) \ ds.  
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there another method that doesn't use Gateaux variation? is it possible to do this from something like first principles?

Comment: As long as you can find a candidate for the derivative then you can use first principle.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to find some candidate for the derivative then

Comment: I know this question is over a year old, but I am having difficulty understanding the first inequality that you used. If you could clarify it, it would be much appreciated

Comment: @mmmmo $\cos(t)$ is positive on $[0, 1]$. Does this help?

Comment: I'm not sure that I see how you got g out of the integral, for the second part i believe you used the fact that cos is between 0 and 1 on [0-x] for x<1 and so its integral is less than the integral of 1 over [0-x] which is x<1.